# What to use in setting up a Speech to Text engine in production?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, speech-to-text

So i have the task to study the feasability of setting up a **Speech-To-Text** engine in a production environnement, and i've been researching on this topic, so I tried ***Google's Speech-To-Text API*** and there is a quota on how many transcribtions you can use daily => That's a **no-no**. Second alternative, **CMU Sphinx** ( Open Source pretrained model for that purpose ), just tested it, and the output is messy for the **LiveSpeech** feature ( Perhaps i need to adjust some parameters first ). Third option, using the available **deep learning** tools to create my own **SpeechRecognition** engine ( I have tons of recorded conversations of people speaking **French** ).

**Question :** What should i use for my case? building an engine from scratch using neural networks seems complicated for a beginner in ML like me, using CMU Sphinx seems easy, but i have a feeling it's not. Any advice on what approach should i follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a gift to the world. I certainly hope someone is working on it even as we speak (ha ha). Let's both keep looking.

Comment: Actually, that gift is being done by the guys at Mozilla. https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech is an open source speech to text engine that is released in English, and other languages will be released as soon as they have enough data.

Comment: you can either use their architecture to train your own model with your own vocals, or use their pre-trained models which have been benchmarked, and are working at levels near Google's and other giant tech companies.